# Rails ActiveModel Serializers render not null attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, attributes, notnull

I want to use a serializer that renders not null attributes

```
     class PersonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
        attributes :id, :name, :phone, :address, :email
     end
```

Is this possible.

Many thanks.

Solution:

```
 class PersonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name, :phone, :address, :email
    def attributes
     hash = super
     hash.each {|key, value|
      if value.nil?
      hash.delete(key)
     end
    }
    hash
   end
  end
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't post answers by editing your question. You should [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) just like others. Please correct this.

Answer (score 17):

From version **0.10.x** of `active_model_serializer` gem, you have to override the method `serializable_hash` instead of `attributes`:

```
# place this method inside NullAttributesRemover or directly inside serializer class
def serializable_hash(adapter_options = nil, options = {}, adapter_instance = self.class.serialization_adapter_instance)
  hash = super
  hash.each { |key, value| hash.delete(key) if value.nil? }
  hash
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Working with AMS 10.0.6

Answer (score 10):

Thanks Nabila Hamdaoui for your solution.
I made it a little more reusable via modules.

**null_attribute_remover.rb**

```
module NullAttributesRemover
  def attributes
    hash = super
    hash.each do |key, value|
      if value.nil?
        hash.delete(key)
      end
    end
    hash
  end
end
```

Usage:

**swimlane_serializer.rb**

```
class SwimlaneSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include NullAttributesRemover
  attributes :id, :name, :wipMaxLimit
end
```

Comment: I wrote it like: `super.keep_if { |_, value| value.present? }`

Comment: Or even shorter: `super.compact`

Comment: @kirushik This is absolutely the best way. The code then becomes: `module NullAttributesRemover
  def attributes(*args)
    super.compact
  end
end`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly i'm need. Working with AMD 10.0.6 (include Andrea Salicetti advice below).

Answer (score 0):

```
class ActiveModel::Serializer
  def attributes
    filter(self.class._attributes.dup).each_with_object({}) do |name, hash|
      val = send(name)
      hash[name] = val unless val.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -4):

Please add validation presence:true in your Person model for (:id, :name, :phone, :address, :email) attributes, so you will get not null JSON value while you render.

Comment: The problem with the presence validation in the model, the attribute will not be null in the database. That's not what I want.

Comment: I have added the solution that I found

Comment: Yes, it will work, but what if attributs i mean key is nil , it will delete , then it will not display in JSON ?

Comment: Yes this is what I want